# How to tweenLite all objects in array and keep distance position?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, gsap

Hey everyone so I have an array of Movie Clip Objects called `aPlanetArray` and what I am trying to accomplish is having all the objects in the array move down to a certain positing and then stop using tweenLite or any other method that would accomplish this. I know I can do it with `y+=2` but I want all objects to move down the screen real quick in a bounce like effect using Tweenlite and to keep their distance ratios.

Here is how I have them setup when added to the stage:

```
//Numbers
        xSpacing = 100;
        ySpacing = 180;
        startPoint = new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2), (stage.stageHeight / 2) );

private function addOuterPlanets():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < nPlanets; i++)
        {
            outerPlanets = new mcOuterPlanets();
            outerPlanets.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
            outerPlanets.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
            stage.addChild(outerPlanets);
            aPlanetArray.push(outerPlanets);

        }
    }
```

and when I tween them I am using this tweenlite function:

```
for each(var allPlanets:mcOuterPlanets in aPlanetArray)
                {
                    TweenLite.to(allPlanets, 5.0, {y:550, ease:Back.easeOut});
                }
```

This works perfect but all objects in array line up together and don't keep their spacing against one another. Any ideas would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: To eliminate the need for looping through and moving each one you could have them all in a parent container and just move that container.

Comment: Yeah see that is what I was thinking of doing. Just never tried that before so was iffy about taking that approach. So just create a empty Movie clip and add the objects in the array to it right? Ill try to fiddle with it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just have all the planets in a parent container and then move the container instead of the planets.

```
var planetContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

function addPlanetsToContainer():void{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < aPlanetArray.length; i++){
        planetContainer.addChild(aPlanetArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And now you can do your tween on `planetContainer`

Now to put the character on a planet, you can either do

```
planet.addChild(character);
```

or

```
character.x = planet.x + planet.parent.x;
character.y = planet.y + planet.parent.y;
```

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean. This works perfectly and solves the issue once I do this as well stage.addChild(planetContainer); One more question I have if you don't mind is now looking back at the last question you helped me with in fixing the collision of the planets what do I have to reference now in order for the character to stay on the correct planet?

Comment: Yes this is the next task. The way I would probably do it is add the character as a child to the planet, but you can do it your way too.  you just have to factor in the fact that the planet is not positioned solely on the stage's X/y coordinates. It's X position is the sum of its declared X value and its parents X value (same for y).

Comment: So you can do something like character.x = planet.x + planet.parent.x (and same for y)

Comment: Okay Thank you I am still messing around with it trying to get it to work. Ill let you know if I get it.

Comment: @Nathan instead of doing `stage.addChild(planetContainer);`, it's actually recommended to do just `addChild(planetContainer);`. There is no visual difference between the two in your case, but a conceptual one.

Comment: Okay thank you. Does it make a big difference? Performance wise? Or will adding stage.addchild cause problems down the line?